# Rails query where attribute equals foo or bar

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to write

```
Model.where("attribute = ? OR attribute = ?", "foo", "bar")
```

using objects like (incorrectly)

```
Model.where(attribute: "foo" || "bar")
```

Especially useful for chaining, e.g.:

```
Model.where(attr_one: "blaz").where("attr_two = ? OR attr_two = ?", "foo", "bar")
```

becomes (incorrectly)

```
Model.where(attr_one: "blaz", attr_two: "foo" || "bar")
```

and the mind is happy.

Comment: The problem with your intention here is that `"foo" || "bar"` evaluates to `"foo"` before ActiveRecord can do anything with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing an array `['foo', 'bar']` in that position will result in the query generating an `IN ()` clause, equivalent to your `attr_two = ? || OR attr_two = ?`:

```
Model.where(attr_one: 'blaz', attr_two: ['foo', 'bar'])
# Or chained:
Model.where(attr_one: 'blaz').where(attr_two: ['foo', 'bar'])
```

Should result in a query like:

```
SELECT model.* FROM model WHERE model.attr_one = 'blaz' AND model.attr_two IN ('foo', 'bar')
```